# Wear OS 3 / API 30, Interactive watch face taps don't show a toast

Tags: wear-os, toast, watch

If you use the latest stable Android studio to create an interactive androidx watch face for API 30 (I used java) and run it on the API 30 Wear OS emulator, the tap handler fails to display its toast. All is good on the API28 emulator.

See here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265982091

Might someone with a real API 30 watch try out the interactive watch face for me please. Its not clear to me whether the bug is in the API 30 Emulator or Wear OS3 itself.

Showing extra info from a watch face or complication tap using a simple (non custom) Toast seems a very reasonable thing to want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any problems with toast in Kotlin in API 30 or 31.

You can check out my full code here as an example:

https://github.com/SarahBass/HoroscopeWatchAndroid/blob/main/MyWatchFace.kt

It tells the user star , moon, and calendar data through toasts. It works well when you import strings too.

Here's a few of my code snippets. Sorry for the sloppiness- I'm texting this from my phone and it is not working as well as hoped. Here is a quick copy paste example :

```
 import android.widget.Toast
 import java.lang.ref.WeakReference
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
 import java.util.*
 import android.hardware.Sensor
 import android.hardware.SensorEvent
 import android.hardware.SensorEventListener
 import android.hardware.SensorManager

override fun onTapCommand(tapType: 
 Int, x: Int, y: Int, eventTime: 
Long) {

        //Shows different methods to 
call strings
        when (tapType) {
            TAP_TYPE_TOUCH -> {
                // The user has 
started touching the screen.
            }
            TAP_TYPE_TOUCH_CANCEL -> 
{
                // The user has 
started a different gesture or 
otherwise cancelled the tap.
            }
            TAP_TYPE_TAP -> {
                getToast()}


                else->{}


        invalidate()
    }

private fun getToast() {

 val frameTime = 
INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS
 val sdf =  SimpleDateFormat("EEE")
 val sdf1 = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE")
 val sdf2 = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM")
 val sdf3 = SimpleDateFormat("d")
 val sdf4 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")
 val sdf5 = SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d yyyy")
 val sdf6 = SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:ss a")
 val sdf7 = SimpleDateFormat("a")
 val d = Date()
 val dayOfTheWeek: String = sdf.format(d)
 val dayOfTheWeekLong: String = sdf1.format(d)
 val monthOfYear: String = sdf2.format(d)
 val dayOfMonth: String =sdf3.format(d)
 val year4digits: String = sdf4.format(d)
 val fullDateSpaces: String = sdf5.format(d)
 val timeSpecific : String = sdf6.format(d)
 val amPM : String = sdf7.format(d)

Toast.makeText(
                    
applicationContext,
                    "$dayOfTheWeek , 
$fullDateSpaces",
                    
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                )}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run your code on the API30 Wear OS emulator? If not, I will give it a go from your github.